# Get ServerContext from web application on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have an asp.net web application that runs on IIS. Can i get the server context directly or i need to open a sharepoint web and get it's context?

Is the ServerContext null?

If i can get it, how?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that we can do it and the ServerContext is not null. We can use this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext context = Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext.Current;
```